# Selecting rows with maximum value, combining WHERE. MAX, and CAST, in spark.sql

Tags: sql, apache-spark, select, apache-spark-sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table in Spark with a `date_string` column of type string.

I am looking to **select rows corresponding to the most recent date**. I thought it would be possible to achieve this in one command, casting the string column to numeric, and selecting rows corresponding to maximum date.

I tried

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    CAST(date_string AS INT) AS date
FROM 
    data.some_table
WHERE 
    date = MAX(date)
```

But this gives me an error

```
Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`date`' given input columns
```

So I tried

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    CAST(date_string AS INT) AS date
FROM 
    data.some_table
WHERE 
    date = (SELECT MAX(date_string) FROM data.some_table)
```

which gives me the same error message.

And

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    (SELECT *, CAST(date_string AS INT) AS date 
    FROM data.some_table)
WHERE 
   date = MAX(date)
```

gives me

```
Error in SQL statement: UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot evaluate expression: max(cast(input[71, string, false] as int))
```

And

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    CAST(date_string AS INT) AS date 
FROM
    data.some_table
WHERE 
    CAST(date_string AS INT) = MAX(CAST(date_string AS INT))
```

gives me the same error message as the previous command.

I am new to both Spark and SQL so I am completely lost here. What is the correct command to achieve what I wanted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be pretty close already. However, you cannot use a column computed in the `FROM` clause within the `WHERE` clause (it is evaluated before the `SELECT` clause).

This should work:

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    CAST(date_string AS INT) AS date
FROM 
    data.some_table
WHERE 
    date_string = (SELECT MAX(date_string) FROM data.some_table)
```

Or, if you need to `cast` before comparing, then:

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    CAST(date_string AS INT) AS date
FROM 
    data.some_table
WHERE 
    CAST(date_string AS INT) = (SELECT MAX(CAST(date_string AS INT)) FROM data.some_table)
```

Note that this supposes that you do want to allow ties. Otherwise, you query can be simplified to use a limiting clause instead:

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    CAST(date_string AS INT) AS date
FROM 
    data.some_table
ORDER BY
    date_string
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thank you! I see why I couldn't get it... The last version of your solution needs a DESC but otherwise works! although I do want to allow ties :))

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to cast the date string to a number.  So this should do what you want:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM data.some_table
ORDER BY date_string DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

This assumes that `date_string` has a reasonable format, such as YYYY-MM-DD.

Second, this only returns one row.  If you can have duplicates, then one method is:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM data.some_table t
WHERE t.date_string = (SELECT MAX(t2.date_string)
                       FROM data.some_table t2
                      );
```